# Solving a weighted minimum dominating set problem with its unweighted counterpart?

Tags: graphs, np-hard, decision-problem, weighted-graphs

### Question

Is it possible to find a solution to the weighted minimum dominating set problem, by solving a (related), unweighted minimum dominating set?

### Elaboration

In essence, can one convert a `weighted_input_graph` into an `unweighted_input_graph` such that the minimum dominating set of the `unweighted_input_graph` contains only the nodes of the minimum dominating set of the `weighted_input_graph`, (along with some new nodes that were created during the conversion)?

### Conversion

With the conversion, I mean:

- adding edges and nodes (based on the edge weights of the `weighted_input_graph`).
- removing all edge weights in the `unweighted_input_graph`.

### Constraints

In response to the comments, the following constraints are specified:

- The conversion should be polynomial.
- I would like the procedure to convert the weighted graph to be "natural". In essence, anyone should be able to apply the conversion on any arbitrary weighted input graph (and find the unweighted input graph as a consequence of the conversion).

### Context

I was wondering whether an algorithm to find a minimum dominating set is sufficient to solve a weighted minimum dominating set algorithm, granted some, relatively cheap, conversion procedure exists. However, I was not able to find any such procedures, and found it challenging to determine whether the below procedure generalises:

### Approach

For each (positive) edge weight `x` with value `w_x` between nodex `u`,`v`, add `w_x` nodes between `u` and `v`, and compute the minimum dominating set of that unweighted graph.

Comment: Do you want the conversion to be efficient (e.g., polynomial time)?  Are your weights small or might they be exponentially large?  Do you insist that the conversion be "natural" or merely that it exist?  What is the context and motivation for this question?